# Efficiently loading list of parquet files with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I am trying to load a large number of parquet files in python pandas and noticed a notable performance difference between two different approaches. Specifically

```
pd.read_parquet("/path/to/directory/")
```

Is more than twice as fast than something like:

```
filelist = glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*")
pd.concat([pd.read_parquet(i) for i in filelist])
```

The reason for want to use the 2nd approach include to pre-filter the parquet files to be loaded, or to load from multiple directories (that contain parquet files with same format etc).

Any tips / guidance appreciated - basically looking to understand how to make the 2nd approach as performant as the first (and/or understanding what kind of magic might be making the 1st approach faster).

Comment: `pd.concat` is not a fast routine, and remember that pandas is all compiled C and Fortran. 
 Making one call that stays in compiled code is always going to be faster than making a whole bunch of calls.  It might actually be faster for you to create a temporary directory, make symbolic links to the files you want, and use the whole-directory version.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts - makes sense... and I had actually wondered doing exactly that (though not helpful for resources on different disks etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function pyarrow.parquet.read_parquet:

- uses an IO thread pool in C++ to load files in parallel.
- concatenate the different files into one table using arrow which is faster than doing it in pandas (pandas isn't very good at concatenating).

It's not very well documented, but `pq.read_parquet` can also accept a list of file names, so you will benefit from all the speed up:

```py
filelist = glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*")
pd.read_parquet(fiellist)
```

Comment: huh.. there you go. Well that was simple (if not - immediately - obvious!). Thanks.